# XSLT breaking down after generation. All attributes are invisible

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've been replacing the following characters, ÁÂÀÄÖÓÔÒØÅÜÉŠŽáâàäöôòøåüéšβźý, and that's working just fine. However, after the xslt the result is missing all the attributes names.

Been looking on stackoverflow and found some great code but for some reason, I can't get it to work properly.

My current code:
`

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:call-template name="ReplaceChars">
        <xsl:with-param name="Input" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="OddChars">ÁÂÀÄÖÓÔÒØÅÜÉŠŽáâàäöôòøåüéšβźý</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="RegChars">AAAAOOOOOAUESZaaaaooooauesszy</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template name="ReplaceChars">
    <xsl:param name="Input"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(replace(replace($Input, 'ß','ss'), 'ẞ', 'SS'), $OddChars, $RegChars)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

`

Working example: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGbZ

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no *attributes* in your XML. What's missing is your *elements*. That's because you're not copying them. Try it this way instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="OddChars">ÁÂÀÄÖÓÔÒØÅÜÉŠŽáâàäöôòøåüéšβźý</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="RegChars">AAAAOOOOOAUESZaaaaooooauesszy</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(replace(replace(., 'ß','ss'), 'ẞ', 'SS'), $OddChars, $RegChars)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that both your question and your stylesheet are tagged `version=1.0"`  - but you are using the `replace()` function which is only available in XSLT 2.0

---

**Added**:

To make this more generic, so that actual attributes are processed too:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="OddChars">ÁÂÀÄÖÓÔÒØÅÜÉŠŽáâàäöôòøåüéšβźý</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="RegChars">AAAAOOOOOAUESZaaaaooooauesszy</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(replace(replace(., 'ß','ss'), 'ẞ', 'SS'), $OddChars, $RegChars)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(replace(replace(., 'ß','ss'), 'ẞ', 'SS'), $OddChars, $RegChars)"/>      
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment() | processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Must have selected the tag to fast, changed it. Thank you for your answer this solves the problem. I see where I went wrong, don't have that much knowledge of xslt.

Comment: @DanielHaley Thanks. Unfortunately, my current testing environment does not provide such warnings. I think I've solved it though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using XSLT 2.0, you can also use an [`xsl:character-map`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps).

It looks like a lot, but you can break the character map out into a separate stylesheet and [`xsl:include`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-include) it.

Example...

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" use-character-maps="cm"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:character-map name="cm">
    <xsl:output-character character="Á" string="A"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="Â" string="A"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="À" string="A"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="Ä" string="A"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="Ö" string="O"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="Ó" string="O"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="Ô" string="O"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="Ò" string="O"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="Ø" string="O"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="Å" string="A"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="Ü" string="U"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="É" string="E"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="Š" string="S"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="Ž" string="Z"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="á" string="a"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="â" string="a"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="à" string="a"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="ä" string="a"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="ö" string="o"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="ô" string="o"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="ò" string="o"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="ø" string="o"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="å" string="a"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="ü" string="u"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="é" string="e"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="š" string="s"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="β" string="s"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="ź" string="z"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="ý" string="y"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="ß" string="ss"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="ẞ" string="SS"/>    
  </xsl:character-map>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGbZ/3

Comment: I like your solution. Reason, this does make it easier to read and update. Especially characters like the ß. No need to replace them first. I already use a replace else ware where there are like 15 replaces within each other..... Not the best solution but it works! I might update it with your code :)